# How Do I Find the Minimum Value of a Running Total by Group In SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, aggregate, cumulative-sum

I am a long time user of all things excel and power query, but I am a complete brain-dead noob when it comes to SQL.

The goal of my project is to find the smallest value in a running total, by group.

I've been able to figure out how to do the base running total.  the next idea I had was to run another query against my running total query, in which I run another aggregate function on the running total column to return the minimum value.  when I do that, the query spins out forever, and then returns an error...

I will note that I am creating SQL code within MS Access as I don't currently have access to an SQL server that I can play with at work.

So first I create a union query to combine multiple tables together and call that query "Combined":

```
    SELECT [ItemCode], '1/1/2010' as [Date], 'IM' as [Type], [WarehouseCode], [QuantityOnHand] as [Qty]
    FROM [IM_ItemWarehouse]
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT [ItemCode], [RequiredDate] as [Date], 'PO' as [Type], [WarehouseCode], [QuantityOrdered] - [QuantityReceived] as [Qty]
    FROM [PO_PurchaseOrderDetail]
    WHERE [QuantityOrdered] - [QuantityReceived] > 0

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT [ItemCode], [PromiseDate] as [Date], 'SO' as [Type], [WarehouseCode], ([QuantityOrdered] - 
    [QuantityShipped])*-1 as [Qty]
    FROM [SO_SalesOrderDetail]
    WHERE [QuantityOrdered] - [QuantityShipped] > 0;
```

Then I go oldschool and use a nested select statement to calculate my running total and call this query "RunTotal":

```
    SELECT t1.[ItemCode], t1.[WarehouseCode], t1.[Date], sum(t1.[Qty]) AS TotalByDate, (SELECT
    sum(t2.[Qty])
    FROM Combined t2
    WHERE t2.[ItemCode] = t1.[ItemCode] AND t2.[WarehouseCode] = t1.[WarehouseCode] AND t2.[Date] <= t1.[Date]) AS RunningTotal
    FROM Combined t1
    GROUP BY t1.[ItemCode], t1.[WarehouseCode], t1.[Date]
    ORDER BY t1.[ItemCode], t1.[WarehouseCode], t1.[Date];
```

and then...stuck...here is what I've tried, but so far the query just spins forever or returns an error:

```
    SELECT [ItemCode], [WarehouseCode], min([RunningTotal])
    FROM RunTotal
    GROUP BY [ItemCode], [WarehouseCode];
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give...I am aware that my running total calculation could be much more efficient using window functions, but since I'm writing these SQL statements in MS Access I don't have access to sexy fancy things like OVER and PARTITION BY...

Example Base Data:

```
Style   Type    Whs Date        Qty
widget  On Hand NVR 1/1/2010    100
widget  On SO   NVR 7/15/2020   -30
widget  On PO   NVR 7/18/2020   50
widget  On SO   NVR 7/19/2020   -10
widget  On SO   NVR 7/20/2020   -60
gizmo   On Hand NVR 1/1/2010    100
gizmo   On SO   NVR 7/15/2020   -100
gizmo   On PO   NVR 7/18/2020   50
gizmo   On SO   NVR 7/19/2020   -20
gizmo   On SO   NVR 7/20/2020   -30
```

Example Running Total:

```
Style   Type    Whs Date        Qty  RunTotal
widget  On Hand NVR 1/1/2010    100  100 
widget  On SO   NVR 7/15/2020   -30  70 
widget  On PO   NVR 7/18/2020   50   120 
widget  On SO   NVR 7/19/2020   -10  110 
widget  On SO   NVR 7/20/2020   -60  50 
gizmo   On Hand NVR 1/1/2010    100  100 
gizmo   On SO   NVR 7/15/2020   -90  10 
gizmo   On PO   NVR 7/18/2020   50   60 
gizmo   On SO   NVR 7/19/2020   -20  40 
gizmo   On SO   NVR 7/20/2020   -10  30
```

Example End Result:

```
Style   Whs MinRunTotal
widget  NVR 50
gizmo   NVR 10
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated my post...thank you for the suggestion...duh that'd be helpful...my bad...

Comment: You will probably have to write the running sum data to a temp table then query that table for the min values.

Comment: Date is a reserved word (intrinsic function). Should not use reserved words as names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntactically, your first query cannot have been compilable in MS Access as the *RunningTotal* correlated aggregate expressoin should be included in `GROUP BY` clause. Practically though, correlated subqueries may not be allowed in `GROUP BY` and you also do not want to group by this rank calculation *during* aggregation. Also, in MS Access running complex operations on an underlying `UNION` query does yield performance issues.

Consider the following setup:

1. Convert underlying union query to temp table:

   ```
   SELECT * INTO mytemptable FROM myUnionQuery
   ```
2. Calculate running total (quasi aggregation).

   ```
   SELECT t.[ItemCode], t.[WarehouseCode], t.[Date], 
          (SELECT SUM(sub.[Qty]) FROM myTempTable sub
           WHERE sub.[ItemCode] = t.[ItemCode] 
             AND sub.[WarehouseCode] = t.[WarehouseCode]
             AND sub.[Date] <= t.[Date]) AS RunningQtyTotal
   FROM myTempTable t;
   ```
3. Aggregate at `[ItemCode]` and `[WarehouseCode]` levels:

   ```
   SELECT q.[ItemCode], q.[WarehouseCode], MIN(q.[RunningQtyTotal]) AS MinRunQtyTotal
   FROM mySelectQuery q
   GROUP BY q.[ItemCode], q.[WarehouseCode]
   ```

Comment: thank you so much for the well thought out response to my question...I really appreciate you taking the time to read and digest my wall of text.  creating a temp table and calculating the running total from that temp table was really clever! and definitely sped up the initial calculations.  I'm thinking I might make a temp table for the secondary calc as well, and aggregate step 3 off of that temp table as well...since the final aggregation is still quite slow (full data set is around 44,000 records)

Comment: Sounds good. Glad to help. Yes, use temp tables as needed. Correlated aggregate queries are not the best for performance. Maybe one day, the Access team will support window functions among other current SQL features per my [suggestion](https://access.uservoice.com/forums/319956-access-desktop-application/suggestions/37193662-upgrade-access-sql-dialect-to-current-ansi-standar).

Comment: that suggestion is awesome.  come on MS Access...didn't realize the language was that outdated!  OH, one thing I noticed when replicating your suggestion, in step 2, SUM(t2.[Qty] is missing a closed paren, and also should be SUM(sub.[Qty]) since you changed the nomeclature of the two tables from t1 and t2 to t and sub (I like your nomenclature better btw...easier to understand)